# express callback not being called in separate module

Tags: javascript, node.js

When trying to call the results.js callback it will not execute. The showDate function will execute and write the console.log. When debugging it seems to exectute the routing functionality.

However when posting to the page from the search.ejs it will give a 404 for the route.

**app.js**

```
var express = require("express");
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
//MongoDB
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/time_report");

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    password: String
});


var user = mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
module.exports = {
    app: express(),
    user
};

var resultJS = require("./results.js");
resultJS.showDate();
```

---

**results.js**

```
var test = require("./app.js");

function showDate() {
console.log("showDate"); // Will execute on application startup
    test.app.post("/results", function(req, res) {
        res.render("results"); //Not executing

    //Get login info
    var uName = req.query.username;
    var pw = req.query.password;

});
}

module.exports.showDate = showDate;
```

Comment: your modules are requiring each other which is quite strange. Theres also no app.listen(), so actually theres no server set up

Comment: I dont think this code will work at first place should have given some error on  `test.app.post`

Comment: Actually it works like it should. It was a chrome restart problem. Note that I didn't post the complete code.